# Is it better to have a default avatar library on client or server side?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, storage, reactjs

I have a webapp using ReactJS as the frontend and Rails as the backend service.

I have an account manager, where a user can choose multiple avatars from a default library. This library contains around 250/300 images, and uses 20Mb of disk space.

I was wondering whether it is a good thing or not to have them stored on the client side. I believe that client side storage is easier to update, since I can just add/remove/rename files from my explorer during development.

However, I hesitate quite a lot, since I am aware of possible performances issues from memory usage. Plus, once uploaded to server, images can be easily retrieved as a URL list, and I won’t have to use file libraries like `fs`. But it’s a pain to upload them all, not to mention I’ll need to use a specific database manager each time I need to update/add/remove a file.

Which is the best practice for this particular case, and given the libraries in use (ReactJS and Rails)?

Comment: Maybe I'm being dense and have missed something in the question where are users supposed to get these images from if they are not stored on the server?

Comment: @AntP In frontend static folder (along with css and other assets).

Comment: @AntP By `storing on server`, I mean in a distant database handled by my backend API. `Storing on client side` refer to files that are sent locally with the frontend API.

Comment: How will the front-end code know that there are new images to retrieve? How will the front-end code know at all which files are avatar images and which are random other images?

Comment: @BartvanIngenSchenau Images won’t change every 2 weeks, maybe not even more than twice a year. Plus, reactjs is designed to dynamically refresh when static content changes (whereas I need to constantly look for update on server side). And since I have control on local assets, I have a specific folder which only contains avatar…

Comment: The best approach is the one that best meets your needs or requirements. What would you say are the needs? You have described 2 solutions but you didn't say what are they solving and it makes impossible for us to say which one is preferable. If there's no special needs or the choice is irrelevant for the project, then choose the simplest one (KISS). The one that is easier to maintain.

Comment: @Laiv Thanks ! Actually choice is irrelevant. Easier choice in given context is to put them on client side. I just had worries about sending a huge assets folder to front since I don’t know how optimization works in reactJS. I think I’ll go with frontend storage.

Comment: If the client option is your simplest solution go ahead. If later, needs change and the solution shift to the server option, just adapt yourself and move it. Let the needs dictate what to do. Don't anticipate because it leads to YAGNI, don't overthink it because it leads to overengineering (in opposition to KISS). Ideally, a solution is as cheap/expensive/complex as the problem it solves.